# apache and mod_mono debugging

Tags: asp.net, apache, mono, debian

I have apache2 and mod_mono installed.
The problem is, that when I request http://myvirtual.mynetwork/My.Services.WebsiteComms.test.aspx, file is downloaded, instead of executed as aspx handler says.

mod_mono is enabled, some usefull settings:

(already applied) /etc/rc.local:

```
if [ ! -e /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register ]; then
        /sbin/modprobe binfmt_misc
    mount -t binfmt_misc none /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
fi
if [ -e /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register ]; then
        echo ':CLR:M::MZ::/usr/bin/mono:' > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
else
        echo "No binfmt_misc support"
        exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

/etc/debian_version:

```
7.1
```

/etc/mono-server4/mono-server4-hosts.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_mono.c>
  MonoUnixSocket default /tmp/.mod_mono_server4
  MonoServerPath default /usr/bin/mod-mono-server4
  AddType application/x-asp-net .aspx .ashx .asmx .ascx .asax .config .ascx
  MonoApplicationsConfigDir default /etc/mono-server4
  MonoPath default /usr/lib/mono/4.0:/usr/lib
</IfModule>
```

(this file is included from apache2 config at /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mono.conf)

/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4 is running, /tmp/.mod_mono_server4 is socket writable for www-data user.

I have documentroot of a virtualhost at /srv/web
I have these files in docroot:

```
My.Services.WebsiteComms.test.aspx
My.Services.WebsiteComms.test.aspx.config
My.Services.WebsiteComms.test.exe
My.Services.WebsiteComms.test.exe.config
My.Services.WebsiteComms.test.pdb
```

.aspx is just a copy of an exe file, which works fine, if I run it through mono ./My.Services.WebsiteComms.test.exe
Both aspx and exe files have +x for www-data (owner).

Answer (score 0):

If that's the whole content of `/etc/mono-server4/mono-server4-hosts.conf` then you didn't set up any applications. You need to add some, either manually or using `mono-server4-admin` and `mono-server4-update` (recommended).